# Pub/Sub using RabbitMQ

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to figure out how to implement pub/sub using ServiceStack MQ abstraction

Let's say I have a publisher app publishing a Hello request that will have n subscribers (different apps)

```
// Publisher
namespace Publisher
{
    public class RabbitPublisherAppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
    {
        public RabbitPublisherAppHost() : base("Rabbit Publisher Server", typeof(MainClass).Assembly) { }

        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            Routes
                 .Add<Publish>("/publish/{Text}");

            container.Register<IMessageService>(c => new RabbitMqServer());

            var mqServer = container.Resolve<IMessageService>();

            mqServer.Start();
        }
    }
}

namespace Publisher
{
    public class PublishService : Service
    {
        public IMessageService MessageService { get; set; }
        public void Any(Publish request)
        {
            PublishMessage(new Hello{Id=request.Text});
        }
    }
}
```

than I create the first subscriber

```
// Sub1
public class RabbitSubscriberAppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    public RabbitSubscriberAppHost() : base("Rabbit Subscriber 1", typeof(MainClass).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<RabbitMqServer>(c => new RabbitMqServer());

        var mqServer = container.Resolve<RabbitMqServer>();

        mqServer.RegisterHandler<Hello>(ServiceController.ExecuteMessage, noOfThreads: 3);
        mqServer.Start();
    }
}

namespace Subscriber1
{
    public class HelloService : Service
    {
        public object Any(Hello req)
        {
            //..
        }
    }
}
```

Now If I create a similar app acting as the second subscriber, the 2 subscribers are sharing the same queue, so instead of the pub/sub a race condition is happening.
In other word, what has to be done to implement a registration for each subscribers? I'd like all subscribers recevive the Hello request published, not just one of them according to a race condition.

Comment: Do you have any updates on your issue? I'm in the same boat as you perfectly described right now. It's been 2 years, so I'm wondering if you found ServiceStack better support for RabbitMQ pub/sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack's [Messaging API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging) follows the Services Request / Reply pattern (i.e. essentially using MQ instead of HTTP transport) and doesn't support Pub/Sub itself.

For RabbitMQ Pub/Sub you would have to implement it outside of the `IMessaging` API abstraction, e.g. publishing it to a Rabbit MQ topic from within your Service implementation.

---

Related ServiceStack does include a [Pub/Sub library using Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#new-managed-pubsub-server). Also depending on your use-case you may be able to make use of notifying [multiple subscribers with Server Events](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Server-Events) .

Comment: Is your answer still true? You answered Jan 2015, but it is now Mar 2017. I am hoping this was true back then, but now SS supports pub/sub. I'm trying to learn the best way to implement pub/sub with RabbitMQ in ServiceStack.

Comment: @MADCookie Yes, ServiceStack's MQ Support [provides an alternative endpoint](http://docs.servicestack.net/messaging#message-workflow) for calling ServiceStack Services, i.e. it's Messaging API doesn't cover pub/sub scenarios. For that you'd need to drop down to [Pub/Sub support in RabbitMQ.Client](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-dotnet.html) where it would be implemented it in the same way as any other Web Framework.